# How can I set image tag to alternating attribute align left to align right

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic pages where elements are always being removed and added. I am aligning the images left right left right.

Rather than having to change this every time someone is added or dropped. How can I add the align attribute to the image tags using jQuery?

```
$(".teamcontainer p img").attr("align","left");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".teamcontainer p img").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).attr('align', index % 2 == 0 ? 'left' : 'right');
});
```

It loops over all `img` elements in the selector, if it is an even numbered item in the loop, it assigns `align = left`, otherwise `align = right`.